# How to get by the cookiewall when scraping webpage with Python's BeautifulSoup and Requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a scraper that will get some data from the web page but the website has a cookiewall that prompts the window where you need to accept the cookies.

When I parse the website's url my scraper gets the data from the popup, not the page itself.

Any ideas how to bypass this?

Comment: If you have a sample url, it could help other users. Ideally you would want to start a session and send the post request for the cookies within that session, but it all depends on the complexity of the page.

Comment: @calestini 
Here's a [link](https://www.mozzartbet.com/en#/) for you. Not sure about the complexity of the page.
Thank you!